# Parsing String to Date during internationalization in gwt

Tags: gwt, internationalization, datetime-format

i am try to parse string to date it works normally well but when i am use internationalization with &locate=fr then it will thrown java.lang.IllegalArgumentException.

hear is the peace of code i want to get date from string.

```
public static Date toDate(String date){
    DateTimeFormat format = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("MM/dd/yy h:mm:s a");
    return format.parseStrict(date);
}
```

and i am try to convert "02/02/2012 10:10:25 AM".

please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [parse()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/DateTimeFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) instead of [parseStrict()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/DateTimeFormat.html#parseStrict%28java.lang.String%29). If you use `parse()` dates are parsed leniently, so invalid dates will be wrapped around as needed. And with `parseStrict()` dates are parsed strictly, so invalid dates will result in an `IllegalArgumentException`. See you are using different format for your date.
`02/02/2012`  which corresponds to `MM/dd/yyyy` not to `MM/dd/yy`

```
public Date parseStrict(java.lang.String text) throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

> Parses text to produce a Date value. An IllegalArgumentException is
>   thrown if either the text is empty or if the parse does not consume
>   all characters of the text. Dates are parsed strictly, so invalid
>   dates will result in an IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: I have already been tried for `parse()` but it thrown same exception every time. I your done because of you just convert in `MM/dd/yyyy` but I want both Date and time so you just try for `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a` than it will throw exception.

Answer (score 0):

instead of standard `DateTimeformat` use `com.google.gwt.i18n.client.DateTimeFormat`